# How to display an image in jsp page?

Tags: java, mysql, image, jsp

I know that this question is being asked a lot but I still have a problem.
I work on a web application using Apache-Tomcat and MySQL database to store the path of each image I want to display but it's not working so please if anyone write me down step by step how to display any image on a jsp page and where exactly I store my images for display on my webapp

Comment: Have you tried an HTML img tag, setting the src to the path of your image?

Comment: Please provide code snippet you are using to display the image and also the url getting formed by your code.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div ><img src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/images/logo.gif"  title="Your Title" /></div>
```

Comment: image path must be inside the webroot i.e.  your image at WebRoot/myimage/my.png then write **<div ><img src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/myimage/my.png"  title="Your Title" /></div>**

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this wouldn't work with regular html, so it would depend on what path you are retrieving from MySQL, meaning if it is the full URL to the file or a relative URL to the file.

In the case of a full URL you just have to do the following:
`<img src="your_full_url_here">`
In the case of a relative URL just prepend or append the missing information to reach the file, such as: `<img src="your_relative_path' + restOfPathVariable>`